# Is it possible to export data to excel keeping the hyperlinks of the table visualization or Details on Demand intact?

Tags: spotfire, tibco

In Spotfire dashboard I have a table visualization and Details on Demand which contains a column which has a "link" renderer. So when I click the value in the column cell it opens a page in browser because I have configured a hyperlink.

Now, I want to export this table to excel, and want to keep the hyperlink intact in excel. So I would like the excel to have a column with the same link as I have in spotfire.

Is this possible in spotfire?